# Get real client IP address in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I implement rate limiting in Spring Cloud Gateway (SCG). I get client IP address with below code

```
@Component
public class RemoteAddressKeyResolver implements KeyResolver {
    @Override
    public Mono<String> resolve(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

My SCG is behind a proxy so it gets address of proxy not real client address. How can I get real client address?

Comment: My proxy added X-Forwarded-* headers, how SCG capture those headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution!. There is an implementation of `RemoteAddressResolver` is `XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver`. Just use it, don't need to implement logic again.

```
@Component
public class RemoteAddressKeyResolver implements KeyResolver {
    @Override
    public Mono<String> resolve(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver resolver = XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver.maxTrustedIndex(1);
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = resolver.resolve(exchange);
        return Mono.just(inetSocketAddress.getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

That's all, so simple!

Comment: Hi, could I ask you about it? I applied this answer to my gateway, but it didn't work.  I'm using nginx as my reverse proxy.  And the SCG is right behind the nginx.  So the overall system structure looks similar with yours.  Is location of this KeyResolver implementation class matters? or any properties settings are required?

Answer (score 1):

you could check your request headers key, like [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) (depends on your proxy settings)

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or a load balancer.

`getFirst` will return the origin ip

```
exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("X-Forwarded-For")
```

Comment: I found SCG implemented `XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver`, how can I use this resolver?

Answer (score 0):

```
    return exchange -> {
        // String origin = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("X-Forwarded-For");
        // if (origin == null) 
        // origin = exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
        // return Mono.just(origin);
        XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver resolver = XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver.maxTrustedIndex(1);
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = resolver.resolve(exchange);
        logger.trace("inetSocketAddress {}", inetSocketAddress);
        logger.trace(".getHostName() {}", inetSocketAddress.getHostName());
        return Mono.just(inetSocketAddress.getHostName());
    };
```